# NLog does not write to file in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nlog

I am using NLog in my Asp.net Core Application, but NLog is not able to write in file, i have all ready change permission of file,but still facing proble. file gets created,on first time but unable to write log in that file.

Here is my nlog.config file code below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="C:\git\damienbod\AspNetCoreNlog\Logs\internal-nlog.txt">

    <targets>
      <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="D:\nlog-all.txt"
                  layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}"
                  keepFileOpen="false"/>
      <target xsi:type="EventLog"
          name="String"
          layout="Layout"
          machineName="String"
          source="Layout"
          category="Layout"
          eventId="Layout"
          log="String"
          maxMessageLength="Integer" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
      <logger name="*" minlevel="*Info*" maxLevel="*Deubg*" writeTo="allfile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

And here is code of my controller

```
NLog.Logger _Logger= LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            _Logger.Info("Hello i m executing");
```

Comment: I have make changes as per your suggestion @The FORCE JB, minlevel="Debug" but still facing same problem

Comment: Is there any error message in internalLogFile? Seems no other incorrect settings, I have a workable NLog.config in [github](https://github.com/KarateJB/Angular2.Mvc/blob/master/Angular2.Mvc/src/Angular2.Mvc.Website/NLog.config), hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this link:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(csproj---vs2017)

You have to enable copy to bin folder for **nlog.config**
[Image copy nlog.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgqU8.png)

Comment: links only answer are prone to be moderated please add some explanation from the provided link.

Comment: Nlog.config needs to be copied at compilation to the bin folder. So go on nlog.config properties and select the option "Copy Always"  for section named "Copy to output directory" :) Hope this helps and clearer than the previous answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the "Info" level is actually has the higher priority than "Debug". Change the config like this might works.

```
 <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" maxLevel="Info" writeTo="File" />
```

Reference : [NLOG Configuration](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#log-levels)

Answer (score 0):

I think your config file should like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="C:\git\damienbod\AspNetCoreNlog\Logs\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- define various log targets -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
     <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="D:\nlog-all.txt"
                 layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" keepFileOpen="false"/>

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" maxlevel="Info"  writeTo="allfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I have removed unnecessary part and also mixlevel and maxlevel as suggested by @The FORCE Jb you have to specify.

Apart from this I can also see that you have type for DEBUG word.

Answer (score 0):

You need the NLog.Extensions.Logging package ([NuGet link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging)) for .NET Core and enable NLog in `startup.cs`:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env,  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  //add NLog to ASP.NET Core
  loggerFactory.AddNLog();

  //configure nlog.config in your project root
  env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

  ...
```

For more information, see the [GitHub page](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.web)